# How can I filter out mailing list threads where I participate in?

Tags: gmail, mailing-list, gmail-filters

I subscribe to a mailing list, where a large number of messages are posted each day. I don't want these mails to disturb me, so I've set up a filter that automatically

- *moves these messages to a certain label* and
- *skips the inbox*

The Gmail filter is:

> Matches: `list:(ffmpeg-user.ffmpeg.org)`
>   Do this: `Skip Inbox, Apply label "Miscellaneous/FFmpeg-Mailing"`

Now, sometimes I'd like to participate in a few threads. I would like those threads *not* to be automatically archived, but appear in my inbox like every other message.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could star the threads you're interested in and edit your filter with:

```
list:(ffmpeg-user.ffmpeg.org) -is:starred
```

If you use the advanced stars features, you can use: (`has:yellow-star`).

More info on advanced stars filters on
[about.com](http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/et_find_mail.htm).

Comment: I have a label `_Waiting`. Can I also use that instead? E.g. don't filter stuff with the `_Waiting` label. It seems `list:(ffmpeg-user.ffmpeg.org) - label:_waiting` shows me just those with this label, which is exactly the opposite of what I want.

Comment: More ideally, isn't there a filter for threads I participate in (e.g. where I have at least one mail sent)?

Comment: @slhck: No, there isn't a filter for threads you're participating in.

Comment: try to remove the space between `-` (minus) and `label:_waiting`. I've made a slight test on search box, removeing the space seems to be important

Comment: This does not work. Stars apply to individual messages, not conversations. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/54708

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to create a filter where it checks for your email address in the "From:" and the mailing list's address in the "To:" and applies a different label.

```
Matches: from:(slhk@example.com) to:(list@ffmpeg-user.com)
Do this: Apply label "participating"
```

It doesn't match exactly what you want to do, but the threads you're participating in will be easily found.

Answer (score 0):

Change filter to:

```
Matches: list:(ffmpeg-user.ffmpeg.org) -from:youridhere@gmail.com
Do this: Skip Inbox, Apply label "Miscellaneous/FFmpeg-Mailing"
```

If you want to include mails directly addressed to you as well as the mailing list, try

```
Matches: list:(ffmpeg-user.ffmpeg.org) -from:youridhere@gmail.com -to:youridhere@gmail.com
Do this: Skip Inbox, Apply label "Miscellaneous/FFmpeg-Mailing"
```

Comment: The second filter returns almost the same results, since the mailing list is always directly sending to me. I don't really get the conversations I participate in.

Answer (score -1):

Visit [Filter Messages from a Mailing List in Gmail](http://googlesystem.blogspot.jp/2007/11/filter-messages-from-mailing-list-in.html).

> If you select "filter messages like this" when you read a message from a mailing list, Gmail will filter the right messages using the listid: operator, that corresponds to the List-ID header. For example, listid:googlepress.googlegroups.com is the best way to find messages sent from the Google Press group. You should create filters that automatically label these messages, archive them or mark them as read.