# Exclude starred messages?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I
[ran a search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/22302)
on my messages including

```
-is:starred
```

I also tried

```
-has:yellow-star
```

however I am still getting starred messages in my search results

[image: star]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Labels appears to work better with conversations, so I am going to go with that.

```
-label:cygwin
```

[image: label]

Answer (score 2):

Those conversations are coming up because stars are applied to individual messages, not conversations. So, at least one message in the conversation lacks the star and so meets your `-is:starred` criterium.

If you star all the messages in that conversation I'll bet the conversation drops out of your search results.

Labels work in much the same way, which is why it can be problematic to search for negative criteria.

Comment: I _think_ if you remove then re-add the star from that view, it'll add a star to the conversation. Then again, it's probably just as likely that it'll just add the star to the latest message.

Comment: Just tried unstarring then restarring the conversation, that doesn't work: it stars the latest message